# Rewrite rules array hide the category from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am using below rewrite rules array for rewrite URLs.

```
$rules = array(
    'image'             => "/image/(?'image'[\w\-]+)",                        // '/image/image-slug'
    'product-category'  => "/product-category/(?'product_category'[\w\-]+)",  // '/product-category/category-slug'
    'product'           => "/product/(?'product'[\w\-]+)",                    // '/product/product-slug'
    'post'              => "/(?'post'[\w\-]+)",                               // '/post-slug'
    'home'              => "/"                                                // '/'
);
```

and here is my .htaccess below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} baqsa\.pk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.baqsa.pk/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

The current URL is like `domain.com/product-category/category-slug` etc.. i want to remove or hide the `product-category` from the URL. I want like this URL `domain.com/category-slug` When I remove the  `product-category` from the array here `'product-category'  => "/(?'product_category'[\w\-]+)",` then it is working fine but then the post `'post' => "/(?'post'[\w\-]+)",`  is not working.. what i am missing here?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please confirm that you want to hit `domain.com/products` in browser and rewrite it to `domain.com/product-category/products` in backend?

Comment: No the current url is ```domain.com/product-category/category-slug``` it is still working. I want to change it to ```domain.com/category-slug``` i want just remove the ```product-category``` from the current url.

Comment: Ok so you are hitting `domain.com/product-category/category-slug` url in browser and you want it to look like `domain.com/category-slug` which should be served by index.php in backend? Kindly confirm once and I could try to help you on same then.

Comment: yes i confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. Change your_site to your actual domain name, also please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://www.your_site%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)/?$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```